# SSLLoadSharedLibrary: Failed to load library libcrypto.so.0.9.8

Tags: permissions, vmware

I am trying to load vmware-vdiskmanager to repair a .vmdk file

As an exmaple

```
vmware-vdiskmanager -R /home/user/vmware/Windows7/Windows7.vmdk
```

I get this error

```
VMware Workstation Error:
VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (app)
SSLLoadSharedLibrary: Failed to load library libcrypto.so.0.9.8:/usr/bin/libdir/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
A core file is available in "/home/user/core".  Please request support and include the contents of the core file.  
To collect data to submit to VMware support, select Help > About and click "Collect Support Data". You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder directly.
We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
```

I have downloaded `libcrypto.0.9.8`, but it is located in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I have tried to create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /usr/bin/libdir/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

I get:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./libcrypto.so.0.9.8’: Permission denied
```

i know I am just missing something very basic on what I need to do to get this point to the right library, I just am looking for what I need to do to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself.  The vmware-vdiskmanager needs i386 libraries.

`sudo aptitude install libssl0.9.8:i386`

If that by itself doesn't solve the problem, look at other related i386 libs.

Shane

Comment: Thank you.  I had looked at other answers on this topic, and had loaded several other related libraries with no success along with trying to create symbolic link.  I loaded the library you referenced above, and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: In my case, the solution was to install `sudo apt install libssl-dev:i386`

Answer (score 0):

In my case as well sudo aptitude install libssl0.9.8:i386 did not work, sudo apt install libssl-dev:i386 fixed the issue however

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter the same problem and solved like this

Download package

`http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1_i386.deb`

Then install it

```
sudo apt install "libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1_i386.deb"
```